# PyGame Collsion Trouble

Tags: python, pygame

I am trying to build a small game that is based off of don't touch the wire (You have to maneuver a circle around a wire/line). I am not too sure where to start to program the collision between the wire and the edge of the circle because the wire randomly moves by itself. Do i have to create a list storing all of the co-ordinates of the line?
Here is the code for it:

```
import pygame
from random import randint

pygame.init()

white = (255, 255, 255)
black = (0, 0, 0)
red = (255, 0, 0)
green = (0, 255, 0)
blue = (0, 0, 255)

display_width = 600
display_height = 600

gameDisplay = pygame.display.set_mode((display_width, display_height))
pygame.display.set_caption("Wire")
font = pygame.font.SysFont("aerial", 20)
clock = pygame.time.Clock()
pygame.display.update()


def text_objects(text, colour):
    textSurface = font.render(text, True, colour)
    return textSurface, textSurface.get_rect()

def message_to_screen(msg, colour, xpos, ypos):
    textSurf, textRect = text_objects(msg, colour)
    textRect.center = (xpos), (ypos)
    gameDisplay.blit(textSurf, textRect)

def gameLoop(FPS):
    start = 0
    from math import pi
    gameExit = False
    gameOver = False
    num_top = 300
    num_bot = 300
    pygame.mouse.set_pos(display_width / 2, display_height / 2)
    line_array =[]
    line_thickness = 8

    while not gameExit:
        mouse = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
        # print(mouse)
        if (start == 0):
            print("Game Started")
        elif(mouse[0] <= 48) or (mouse[0] >= 547) or (mouse[1] <= 25) or (mouse[1] >=585):
            gameOver = True
        start += 1
        if gameOver == True:
            gameDisplay.fill(white)
            message_to_screen("You Lost", red, 300, 300)
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                gameExit = True
            if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
                if event.key == pygame.K_q:
                    gameExit = True

        rand_nums = [randint(-3, 3), randint(-3, 3)]
        num_top += rand_nums[0]
        num_bot += rand_nums[1]
        message_to_screen("Press q or the x button to quit", blue, 100, 40)
        pygame.display.update()
        gameDisplay.fill(white)
        pygame.draw.arc(gameDisplay, red, [mouse[0]-48, mouse[1]-25, 100, 40], 0, pi, 3)
        pygame.draw.line(gameDisplay, black, [num_top, 0], [num_bot, 600], line_thickness)
        pygame.draw.arc(gameDisplay, red, [mouse[0]-48, mouse[1]-25, 100, 40], 3 * pi, 2 * pi, 3)

        clock.tick(FPS)

    pygame.quit()
    quit()
gameLoop(100)
```

Comment: you have to check only two points from circle if they ar on black line - and there is math method to check if one point is on line. You need only start and end point of line. You don't have to list of all points on line.

Comment: how do i do that when i have only specified the starting and ending point of the line? do i have to create a list of the pixels?

Comment: http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/26004/how-to-detect-2d-line-on-line-collision

Answer (score 0):

I calculate angles (see red and green angle on image) and compare them. If they are almost identical then point is on line - so there is collision.

Because `float` gives not ideal results so I have to compare if angles are **almost** identical.

```
if -0.01 < tanges_angle - tanges_angle_p1 < 0.01:
```

It may need smaller or bigger values than `0.01`

To calculate first angel (green) I need only bottom point and top point of black line. To calculate second angle I need bottom point of black line and point on circle.

[image]

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import pygame
from random import randint
from math import pi

# --- constants --- (UPPER_CASE names)

WHITE = (255, 255, 255)
BLACK = (  0,   0,   0)
RED   = (255,   0,   0)
GREEN = (  0, 255,   0)
BLUE  = (  0,   0, 255)

DISPLAY_WIDTH = 600
DISPLAY_HEIGHT = 600
CENTER_X = DISPLAY_WIDTH//2
CENTER_Y = DISPLAY_HEIGHT//2

FPS = 30

LINE_THICKNESS = 8

PI_2 = 2*pi
PI_3 = 3*pi

# --- functions --- (lower_cas names)

def render_text(text, colour):
    image = font.render(text, True, colour)
    rect  = image.get_rect()
    return image, rect

def message(screen, msg, colour, x, y):
    image, rect = render_text(msg, colour)
    rect.center = (x, y)
    screen.blit(image, rect)

def gameloop():

    num_top = 300
    num_bot = 300

    pygame.mouse.set_pos(CENTER_X, CENTER_Y)

    start = True
    game_exit = False
    game_over = False

    while not game_exit:

        # - events -

        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                game_exit = True
            if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
                if event.key == pygame.K_q:
                    game_exit = True

        # - updates -

        m_x, m_y = pygame.mouse.get_pos()

        if start:
            print("Game Started")
            start = False
        elif (m_x <= 48) or (m_x >= 547) or (m_y <= 25) or (m_y >= 585):
            game_over = True

        if game_over == True:
            screen.fill(WHITE)
            message(screen, "You Lost", RED, 300, 300)

        num_top += randint(-3, 3)
        num_bot += randint(-3, 3)

        # proportion

        dx = num_bot - num_top
        dy = DISPLAY_HEIGHT
        tanges_angle = dx/dy

        dx_p1 = num_bot - (m_x-48) # or smaller ie. m_x-46
        dy_p1 = DISPLAY_HEIGHT - m_y
        tanges_angle_p1 = dx_p1/dy_p1

        if -0.01 < tanges_angle - tanges_angle_p1 < 0.01:
            print('Collide left')

        dx_p2 = num_bot - (m_x+48) # or smaller ie. m_x+46
        dy_p2 = DISPLAY_HEIGHT - m_y
        tanges_angle_p2 = dx_p2/dy_p2

        if -0.01 < tanges_angle - tanges_angle_p2 < 0.01:
            print('Collide right')

        # - draws -

        screen.fill(WHITE)

        pygame.draw.arc(screen, RED, (m_x-48, m_y-25, 100, 40), 0, pi, 3)
        pygame.draw.line(screen, BLACK, (num_top, 0), (num_bot, 600), LINE_THICKNESS)
        pygame.draw.arc(screen, RED, (m_x-48, m_y-25, 100, 40), PI_3, PI_2, 3)

        message(screen, "Press q or the x button to quit", BLUE, 100, 40)

        pygame.display.update()

        # - FPS -

        clock.tick(FPS)

    # - end -

    pygame.quit()
    quit()

# --- main ---

pygame.init()

screen = pygame.display.set_mode((DISPLAY_WIDTH, DISPLAY_HEIGHT))
pygame.display.set_caption("Wire")

font = pygame.font.SysFont("aerial", 20)
clock = pygame.time.Clock()

gameloop()
```

---

It uses comparition `dx/dy == dx_p1/dy_p1` which is based od **intercept theorem**, also known as [Thales' theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intercept_theorem)